# Using getters, methods and calculated properties in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm wondering about the difference on how I add calculated properties to a domain model.  I'm using ASP.NET with Entity Framework.

Firstly I realise I can do:

```
public decimal TotalValue { get; set; }
```

Which is a standard database column.

I can also create a method:

```
public decimal TotalValue()
{
    return this.Invoices.Sum(x => x.Value)
}
```

which is calculated whenever the object is created? Accessed? Or only when I access the method?

What is the difference in that example to this one:

```
public decimal TotalValue
{
    get 
    {
        return this.Invoices.Sum(x => x.Value)
    }    
}
```

Is this the same as the previous example? It appears from looking at the debugger that this value is constantly being calculated anytime I retrieve the parent object, so strikes me as being inefficient?

Finally, I recently learned I can do this:

```
public decimal TotalValue
{
    get 
    {
        return this.Invoices.Sum(x => x.Value)
    }    
    set
    { 
    }
}
```

This piece of magic basically seems to me to be the same as the previous option, however it saves this value in the database - although to me it seems pretty hit and miss as to whether it gets the value from the database or calculates / updates it.

What is everyone else using, and what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: As I understand you want to add property to your model which should not be stored in database am I right?

Comment: Just trying to understand which of these options are suitable for my requirements, and the pros and cons of each

Comment: Both will be calculated when call or access it. You can add *Ignored* property to not relate it with database.